# Windows 10 - DB2 / ODBC / .NET connection to AS400 / V4R3M0

Tags: db2, odbc, ibm-midrange

I am looking for a way to establish a database connection to a AS400 Release V4R3M0 via ODBC or even better with .NET. Under Windows XP I can access the AS400 with the ODBC interface and the driver from the IBM Client Access software. But my release is not working under Windows 10. I have downloaded the IBM Data Server Client Packages - Version 11.5. But I could not establish a connection with it.

I tried it with ODBC Datasource configuration and with the commandline
db2cli execsql -connstring "DATABASE=databasename;HOSTNAME=as400;PORT=8471;UID=user;PWD=password;"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Uninstall the IBM Data Server client, download and install the "IBM i access" with correct options. Read this https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions

Comment: I tried to connect to the AS400 with the app in the IBMiAccess_v1r1.zip package. acsbundle.jar. When I try to do a SQL query I get the error message MSGSY1008. I also installed the IBMiAccess_v1r1_WindowsAP_English.zip package. But the .Net documentation that is supposed to come with the package is missing.

Comment: As you are using an antique (V4R3M0) version of the i-series software, you are on your own.  You might try with very old versions of the client software, but they might not run on Windows-10. Try using a VM running XP if you have the relevant skills.

Comment: This might work. Got any ideas how to create an interface between the VM(WinXP) and Win 10?

Comment: Shared files perhaps the easiest.

Comment: I wrote a small script that starts a tcp server which pulls the sql request via ODBC and sends it to the client

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll need a rather old version of the IBM ODBC driver. Newer versions yield a password error when connecting to very old systems. I'm using the driver from iseriesaccess for linux 7.1.0-2. I guess the same applies to Windows.

Please realise that V4R3 is from 1998 and it will get increasingly hard to find ways to get functioning connections to it from modern Windows systems.

Comment: Note that the iSeries Access for Linux 7.1 an lower require an older version of unixODBC which uses 32-bit types even on 64-bit systems. You will get crashes when using modern unixODBC versions. A workaround is to use the 32-bit driver, but you may need to find an older, 32-bit version of Linux to get that to work.